# Photoshop scripting. Opening & Saving overlapping image stacks

Tags: javascript, image, stack, photoshop-script

I’ve been getting more and more into star photography and have recently been trying to develop a new style of stacking the photos and creating time-lapse videos from the stacked photos.

Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBE3vUb-dtE

This process took absolutely forever to accomplish and I’ve been trying my hardest to write a script to help me automate the process. Each frame is a stack of up to 25 images, then the next frame is an overlapping stack of images, only offset by 1 or 2 photos.
Can anyone please assist me is writing a Photoshop script to accomplish the following?
After taking my time-lapse photos, I am left with a single folder with an image sequence of anywhere between 50 & 1800 photos.

Ideal Setup:

1) Open Photoshop and run a script “Stacked Timelapse”

2) A Dialog box prompts me for the Source ImageSequence  folder. It also prompts me for the maximum length of the stacked star trails (Max number of images to stack per frame).
Ideally it would have some text with recommended settings.

For example:

“0-299 images = Recommended Length of 25”

“300-599 images = Recommended length of 40”

“600+ images = Recommended length of 60”

3) Once you click GO, the script will begin importing the photos into a Stack, applying the ‘.blendMode = BlendMode.LIGHTEN;” to all the layers, then save to a new subfolder (we can call it “Stack”) with the filenames “0001.jpg, 0002.jpg, 0003.jpg, etc” (using max jpg quality settings)

To accomplish the effect in the video, you have to follow this image quantity and offset.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/50801/StarFileStructure.jpg

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to script and accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is possible to script. Can you describe the process of creating each frame a bit more. (which files are in frame 1 & frame 2 etc) How many files are in the source file? What size are the source files in terms of pixel width and height? What is the length? Is that the number of images in the stack?? I'm taking a guess and saying if there are 600 images then the stack is 60 images high, which blend together to make one frame. And you'll end up with either 60 frames or 100 (that's where I'm a little confused) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you should look at the source code for the **Load Files into Stack**, **Merge to HDR Pro** or **Photomerge** features.  These are partially implemented in ExtendScript, and the script's source code is provided as part of the Photoshop release.  I think their basic operation is similar to what you're trying to accomplish.  Load Files into Stack is probably the simplest one to start with.

The source code to these files is found in:

```
Photoshop_App_Folder/Presets/Scripts/
   Load Files into Stack.jsx
   Photomerge.jsx
   Merge to HDR.jsx
   Stack Scripts Only/
      CreateImageStack.jsx
      StackSupport.jsx
```

where `Photoshop_App_Folder` is `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CSn` on Windows and `/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CSn` on the Mac.

These features use a library of code in the sub-folder `Stack Scripts Only/` to do the basic tasks of managing the UI and loading the photo files into a layered document.

This stuff is not uncomplicated, but looking at these scripts gives you working examples to use as a starting point.  Also, if you're not familiar with the [Extendscript Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scripting.html), I would start learning about it first.  It's the IDE used to develop scripts for Photoshop and other Creative Suite apps.